# Tensorial Representation of a Complex Network (Questions on Tensors)

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, network, tensor-rank, complex-systems

---

### **INTRODUCTION TO QUESTION 1**

Some authors proposed a tensorial representation of [complex networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_network) (for both single layer networks and multilayer networks). One reference paper for this topic is this one:

[M. De Domenico et al., Mathematical Formulation of Multilayer Networks. Physical Review X 3, 041022 (2013)](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.3.041022)

(note: the same tensorial representation of complex networks was treated also in the section "2.1 Tensorial Representation of a Complex Network" of a recent book: [O. Artime et al., Multilayer Network Science: From Cells to Societies. Elements in Structure and Dynamics of Complex Networks  (2022)](https://www.cambridge.org/ch/academic/subjects/physics/statistical-physics/multilayer-network-science-cells-societies?format=PB&isbn=9781009087308))

I rewrite here a few sentences from that paper (which basically come from the beginning of the section ``II. SINGLE-LAYER (MONOPLEX) NETWORKS''), to introduce and better understand my questions.

> - Given a set of $N$ **objects** $n_i$ (where $i=1,2,...,N$ and $N \in    \mathbb{N}$), we associate with each object a **state** that is
>   represented by a **canonical vector** in the vector space
>   $\mathbb{R}^N$.
> - More specifically, let $\mathbf{e}_{i} \equiv    (0,...,0,1,0,...,0)^\mathsf{T}$, where $\mathsf{T}$ is the
>   transposition operator, be the column vector that corresponds to the
>   object $n_i$ (which we call a **node**).
> - The $i$th-component of $\mathbf{e}_{i}$ is $1$, and all of its other    components are $0$.
> - One can **relate the objects** $n_i$ **with each other**, and our **goal** is to find a simple way to **indicate** the presence of the **intensity of such relationships**.
> - The most natural choice of vector space for describing the **relationship** is created using the **tensor product** (i.e. the Kronecker product) $\mathbb{R}^N \otimes \mathbb{R}^N = \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$.
> - Thus, second order (i.e., rank-2) **canonical tensors** are defined by $\mathbf{E}_{ij} = \mathbf{e}_{i} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{j}^\mathsf{T}$, where $i,j=1,2,...,N$.
> - Consequently, if $w_{ij}$ indicates the **intensity of the relationship** from object $n_i$ to object $n_j$, we can write the
>   **relationship tensor** as: $\mathbf{W} = \sum_{i,j=1}^N w_{ij} \mathbf{E}_{ij} = \sum_{i,j=1}^N w_{ij} \mathbf{e}_{i} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{j}^\mathsf{T}$, where $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^N \otimes \mathbb{R}^N$.

**Note for people who are not familiar with complex networks.** Basically, the matrix representation of the **relationship tensor** $\mathbf{W}$ would be the so-called **adjacency matrix**, used in the field of complex networks to indicate where edges are present among nodes, and also, to indicate the strength/intensity of those edges, just using the object $w_{ij}$. For example, the adjacency matrix of this tiny network, composed of three nodes (indicated by $n_1$, $n_2$ and $n_3$), is the following:

[image]

Therefore, in this example, the **relationship tensor** $\mathbf{W}$ would be written as follows:

\begin{align}
\mathbf{W} 
       &= \begin{aligned}[t]
\sum_{i,j=1}^3 w_{ij} \mathbf{e}_{i} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{j}^\mathsf{T} = 
0 ( \mathbf{e}_{1} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{1}^\mathsf{T} ) + 
w_{12} ( \mathbf{e}_{1} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{2}^\mathsf{T} ) + 
w_{13} ( \mathbf{e}_{1} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{3}^\mathsf{T} ) + 
w_{21} ( \mathbf{e}_{2} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{1}^\mathsf{T} ) + 
w_{22} ( \mathbf{e}_{2} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{2}^\mathsf{T} ) + 
0 ( \mathbf{e}_{2} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{3}^\mathsf{T} ) + 
w_{31} ( \mathbf{e}_{3} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{1}^\mathsf{T} ) + 
0 ( \mathbf{e}_{3} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{2}^\mathsf{T} ) +
0 ( \mathbf{e}_{3} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{3}^\mathsf{T} )
       \end{aligned}\\
       &= \begin{aligned}[t]
w_{12}
\Biggl(
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 \\
   0 \\ 
   0
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\Biggr) 
+
w_{13}
\Biggl(
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 \\
   0 \\ 
   0
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\Biggr) 
+
w_{21}
\Biggl(
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   1 \\ 
   0
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\Biggr)
+
w_{22}
\Biggl(
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   1 \\ 
   0
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\Biggr)
+
w_{31}
\Biggl(
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 \\ 
   1
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\Biggr)
       \end{aligned}\\
       &= \begin{aligned}[t]
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & w_{12} & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0\\ 
   0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & w_{13}\\
   0 & 0 & 0\\ 
   0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0\\
   w_{21} & 0 & 0\\ 
   0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & w_{22} & 0\\ 
   0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0\\ 
   w_{31} & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
       \end{aligned}\\
       &= \begin{aligned}[t]
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & w_{12} & w_{13}\\
   w_{21} & w_{22} & 0\\ 
   w_{31} & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
       \end{aligned}
\end{align}

---

### **QUESTION 1**

As far as I know, a tensor is a combination of vectors and covectors, and it is invariant under a change of basis. Therefore, I would have expected that the tensor $\mathbf{W}$ would have been introduced as a tensorial product of a vector and a covector, both including their components and bases. Instead, to me, it looks like the authors just used the vector and covector bases,  i.e. $\mathbf{e}_{i} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{j}^\mathsf{T}$ to define the tensor $\mathbf{W}$, and not the (vector and covector) components as well. And just in a second moment, they added the elements $w_{ij}$ somehow "artificially" to the tensor (indeed, the authors wrote exactly: "Consequently, **if** $w_{ij}$ indicates the intensity of the relationship from object $n_i$ to object $n_j$"). I explain here better what I would have expected to introduce the tensor $\mathbf{W}$. If we consider a vector $\vec{v}=\sum_i v^i \vec{e_i}$ and a covector $c =\sum_j c_j \epsilon^j$, then, I would introduce $\mathbf{W}$ as follows:

\begin{align}
\mathbf{W} 
       &= \begin{aligned}[t]
          \vec{v} \otimes c 
       \end{aligned}\\
       &= \begin{aligned}[t]
          \sum_{i,j} v^i \vec{e_i}  \otimes c_j \epsilon^j 
       \end{aligned}\\
       &= \begin{aligned}[t]
          \sum_{i,j} v^i c_j ( \vec{e_i}  \otimes \epsilon^j ) 
       \end{aligned}\\
       &= \begin{aligned}[t]
          \sum_{i,j} w^i_j ( \vec{e_i}  \otimes \epsilon^j ) 
       \end{aligned}
\end{align}

where:

- $\vec{e_i}  \otimes \epsilon^j$ would be the Kronecker product among the **basis vector** $\vec{e_i}$ and the **basis covector** $\epsilon^j$, equivalent to what written by the authors, i.e.
  $\mathbf{e}_{i} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{j}^\mathsf{T}$ (with a sligtly different notation),
- $v^i$ and $c_j$ are the **vector components** and the **covector components**, respectively,
- $w^i_j := v^i c_j$ would result from the product between the vector components and the covector components of the "input" vector and covector.
- By introducing $\mathbf{W}$ in this way, I would write the map as follows: $\mathbf{W}: V \otimes V^* \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N \otimes \mathbb{R}^N$

Therefore,  my question(s):

- **Is my reasoning about the introduction of the tensor $\mathbf{W}$ wrong, compared to the way the authors did in their paper?**
- **Or is it a normal procedure to define a tensor just using the second-order (i.e., rank-2) canonical tensor $\mathbf{E}_{ij} = \mathbf{e}_{i} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{j}^\mathsf{T}$, and then add the elements $w_{ij}$ to it ?**
- **What is the physical meaning of vector and covector, for the authors, in their paper?**

---

### **INTRODUCTION TO QUESTION 2**

In the same section of that paper, just after the introduction of $\mathbf{W}$, the authors added something to the previous definition of $\mathbf{W}$.

> - We will use the **covariant notation** introduced by Ricci and Levi- Civita.
> - In this notation, a **row vector** $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ is given by a **covariant vector** $a_\alpha$ (where
>   $\alpha=1,2,...,N$), and the corresponding **contravariant vector**
>   $a^\alpha$ (i.e., its dual vector) is a **column vector** in Euclidean
>   space.
> - To avoid confusion, we will use **latin letters** $i,j,...$ to indicate, for example, the $i$-th **vector**, the $(ij)$-th
>   **tensor**, etc., and we will use **greek letters** $\alpha,\beta,...$ to indicate the **components of a vector or a tensor**.
> - With this terminology, $e^{\alpha}(i)$ is the $\alpha$-th **component** of the $i$-th **contravariant canonical vector** $\mathbf{e}_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$, and $e_{\alpha}(j)$ is the
>   $\alpha$-th **component** of the $j$-th **covariant canonical
>   vector** in $\mathbb{R}^N$.
> - With these conventions, the **adjacency tensor** $\mathbf{W}$ can be represented as a **linear combination of tensors** in the canonical
>   basis: $W^{\alpha}_{\beta} = \sum_{i,j=1}^N w_{ij} e^{\alpha}(i) \otimes e_{\beta}(j) = \sum_{i,j=1}^N w_{ij} E^{\alpha}_{\beta}(ij)$
> - Here, $E^{\alpha}_{\beta}(ij) \in \mathbb{R}^N \times \mathbb{R}^N$ indicates the tensor in the canonical basis that corresponds to the
>   tensor product of the canonical vectors assigned to nodes $n_i$ and
>   $n_j$ (i.e. $\mathbf{E}_{ij}$).
> - The adjacency tensor $W^{\alpha}_{\beta}$ is of mixed type: it is 1-covariant and 1-contravariant.

---

### **QUESTION 2**

Now, I am very confused.

- **What is the need to introduce $W^{\alpha}_{\beta}$ after $\mathbf{W}$ ? Was not $\mathbf{W}$ enough to get the adjacency tensor/matrix ?**
- **What is the the difference between $W^{\alpha}_{\beta}$ and $\mathbf{W}$ ?**
- **What is the the interpretation of $W^{\alpha}_{\beta}$ (in comparison to $\mathbf{W}$) ?**

@eigenchris (or @[eigenchris](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/52172/eigenchris)): it would be interesting to know your opinion on this topic as well!

Comment: Hey guys :-) ....anyone who can help here? I would be very grateful for any hint in this regard :-)